# How to retrieve the correct message queue response in IBM MQ using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am currently testing IBM MQ request using JSR223 sampler in JMeter. My scenario here is, i need to sent the request to one queue name(Queue.In) and retrieve the response from another queuename(Queue.out). Now i am able to retrieve the response from Queue.out but i am not sure it's extracting the correct message that i have sent or some other message request is in queue already(FIFO model).

May, i know how to modify my below code to send the message id/correlation id to Queue.IN and retrieve the same message id/corelation id from Queue.out or Please do suggest if there is any better approach to extract the same messages from Queue.out.

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQAsyncStatus
import com.ibm.mq.MQMessage
import com.ibm.mq.MQPutMessageOptions
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager
import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC
import com.ibm.mq.constants.MQConstants
import com.ibm.mq.headers.MQRFH2

def mqProps = new Hashtable<String, Object>()
mqProps.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, 'xxxx')
mqProps.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414)
mqProps.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, 'xxx')

def hostName = "${p_hostName}"
def hostPort = ${p_hostPort}
def channelName = "${p_channelName}"
def qManager = "${p_queueManagerName}"
def queueName = "${p_queueName}"

def qMgr = new MQQueueManager(qManager, mqProps)
def openOptions = MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQConstants.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF
def queue = qMgr.accessQueue(queueName, openOptions)

def pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions()
pmo.options = MQConstants.MQPMO_ASYNC_RESPONSE
def message = new MQMessage()
message.format = CMQC.MQFMT_RF_HEADER_2
def rfh2 = new MQRFH2()
rfh2.setEncoding(CMQC.MQENC_NATIVE)
rfh2.setCodedCharSetId(CMQC.MQCCSI_INHERIT)
rfh2.setFormat(CMQC.MQFMT_STRING)
rfh2.setNameValueCCSID(1208)
rfh2.setFieldValue('usr', '${Var1}', '${Var2}')


rfh2.write(message)

message.writeString('''${request_payload}''')

queue.put(message, pmo)
queue.close()

MQAsyncStatus asyncStatus = qMgr.getAsyncStatus()
log.info('Successfully published: ' + asyncStatus.putSuccessCount + ' message(s)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the correlation id into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
vars.putObject('correlationId', message.correlationId)
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

then in order to retrieve a particular message you need to do something like:

```
def queueOptions = new MQGetMessageOptions()
queueOptions.options = CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_CONVERT
queueOptions.matchOptions = CMQC.MQMO_MATCH_CORREL_ID
def response = new MQMessage()
response.correlationId = vars.getObject('correlationId')

queue.get(response, queueOptions)
```

More information: [Getting a particular message](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/7.5?topic=queue-getting-particular-message)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. for your response. But my above code is not generating any correlation ID. How can i fix that issue. I mean it's not showing any response message in response body. Could you please help here.

Comment: Of course it won't show anything because in case of using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) you need to manually set the response data, something like `SampleResult.setResponseData(response.readUTF(), 'UTF-8')`. You may find some useful code snippets in the [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how) article

Comment: Oh okay sure. I will check this article. Thanks @Dmitri